# C fscanf read pointer to array of characters

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read lines from a file into a pointer to a character array using fscanf. I am getting segmentation faults when I print. What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a function other than fscanf?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define MAXSTACK 100
#define MAXLENGHT 100

void main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  char *filename;
  FILE *fp;
  char *lines[MAXSTACK];
  char * command;
  int top = 0;
  int numlines = 0;

  if(argc < 3){

    fprintf(stderr,"error: Not enough arguments provided\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  filename = argv[1];
  command = argv[2];

  if ( (fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL ){

    fprintf(stderr,"error: Cannot open file %s\n",filename);
    exit(1);
  }
  else{

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        fscanf(fp,"%s",lines[i]);
    //    printf("%s\n",lines[i]);
    }

    char **ptr2 = lines;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

         printf("%s\n", ptr2[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(command,"pop")==0){

      //pop(lines);
     }else if (strcmp(command,"print_top")==0){
      //print_top();

    }else if(strcmp(command,"swap_top")==0){

    }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have no array of characters. You have an array of pointers to nothing in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read lines using `fgets`:

```
/* Read a single line into a temporary buffer */
char lineBuffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), fp) != NULL) {
    /* Process the read line */
}
```

Once you have read a line in the temporary buffer, you can deep-copy the read string into some memory that you allocated on the heap using `malloc` (or you can just use `strdup`), and then you can store a pointer to that memory into your `lines` array:

```
 /* Inside the body of the while loop */

 /* 
  * Deep copy current line into the string pointer array.
  * strdup = malloc + strcpy
  * Note that free is required to release memory!
  */
 lines[currLineIndex] = strdup(lineBuffer);

 currLineIndex++;
```

Note that when you write code like this:

> ```
> char *lines[MAXSTACK];
> ```

you are allocating on the stack an array of `MAXSTACK` items, each item being a `char*` pointer. But then you have to give some meaningful value to those pointers (for example: *allocating some memory* from the heap and pointing to that memory).

Of course, when you are done, you have to scan the whole array and call `free` on each element pointer to avoid memory leaks.

Moreover, a good coding practice would be to *clear* the pointers in the array before using it, e.g.:

```
memset(lines, 0, sizeof(lines));
```

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf("%s", lines[i])` will read a sequence of non-white-space characters (note, not a whole line) into the memory pointed to by `lines[i]`. The problem is, that you haven't set `lines[i]` to point to any memory and that is why you get the segfault, you're asking for a sequence of characters to be copied to some undefined location.

If you replace your declaration of an array of character pointers, `char *lines[MAXSTACK];`, with a declaration of an array of arrays of characters `char lines[MAXLENGTH][MAXSTACK]` then `lines[i]` will be an array of `MAXLENGTH` characters which `fscanf("%s", lines[i])` which be able to copy to without seg faulting.

The question remains now, what happens if the string fscanf tries to read is longer than `MAXLENGTH`? The answer is more characters will be read than can fit into the `lines[MAXLENGTH]` array and you get what is called a buffer overflow. To safeguard against this you can limit the maximum number of characters `fscanf` will read from a string, to 100 for example, with `fscanf("%100s", lines[i])`